# You are not authorised to view this resource Joomla issue

Tags: ssl, joomla

I am having some difficult time resolving this issue in Joomla with the error saying:

"You are not authorised to view this resource".

I have tried clearing all kind of cache, browser, joomla cache etc. but still getting the above same error on my ssl secured site.

Comment: There's a known issue in the Joomla tracker like this. http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=29000  Do you think yours is the same?

Comment: I am not sure but my error seems to have resolved after applying what I have mentioned below, which is basically moving between encrypted and unencrypted pages.

Comment: *sorry I meant NOT moving between encrypted and unencrypted pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok basically I've gone to realize that switching between secured(https) and unsecured(http) pages can log a joomla user out.
I am using html forms to pass data between pages and in one of them my form action attribute didn't have the https prefix. Adding it to the form action url was basically the solution.

That solved my issue.